# List cannot be applied to double (using upper bounded wild-card)

Tags: java

I am new to generics, so bear with me.

I was sure I understood what this statement meant:

```
 List<? extends Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
```

To me, it means List will accept any objects added to the list which are of the `Number` class or extend the `Number` class.

So when I added a double to the list, I expected it to work

```
List<? extends Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
nums.add(3.14);
```

However, I get the error `List cannot be applied to double`

Comment: You cant add anything to a Collection which has `? extends T`

Comment: But I thought that is how upper bounded wild cards worked.

Comment: You need  to use `? super Double`. Go through the post I used to close your question as dupe

Comment: But Double extends Number.

Comment: `? extends T` acts as a *Producer* so you cant add anything to it

Comment: This is mind boggling.

Comment: Indeed it is.. So you got the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes. Thanks Lost Mind.

Comment: @the_prole it's not so mind boggling when you think of it the right way.  `List<? extends Number> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>()` is valid, but you can't do `nums.add(3.14)` for an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  It looks like what you want is a `List<Number>`.  Not a `List<? extends Number>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was trying to understand parameterized types in the context of creating generic methods e.g. from the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html). I'm confused because I can have a parameterized paramter ArrayList<? extends Number> and can accept any kind of integer, double, etc. But I cannot declared a paramterized ArrayList in the same way, and add double and integers to it... understand why I'm confused? I don't know if I make any sense. I apologize for that.

Comment: @the_prole You can't add doubles or integers to it because you don't know _which one_ it takes, doubles or integers or something else.  If you know you can add _any_ `Number`, whether it's a double or an integer, then you should have a `List<Number>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Okay, I get it now. Whoa.